# В чем проблема моего жёсткого диска?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, hdd

Хотелось бы понять, **откуда столько непонятных разделов** у меня на жёстком диске и для чего они нужны?

Не то что бы это являлось проблемой, но я раньше замечал это, когда нужно было *отформатировать флешку* или произвести какие-то *манипуляции с файловой системой*. Самостоятельно я эти разделы не добавлял, но посмотрите, что выдаёт мне из раза в раз приложение **fdisk** :

```
➜  ~ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for leviathan: 
Disk /dev/loop0: 104.13 MiB, 109182976 bytes, 213248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 950.41 MiB, 996564992 bytes, 1946416 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 950.42 MiB, 996573184 bytes, 1946432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 104.56 MiB, 109625344 bytes, 214112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 98.99 MiB, 103772160 bytes, 202680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 99.18 MiB, 103993344 bytes, 203112 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 55.46 MiB, 58142720 bytes, 113560 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 55.43 MiB, 58114048 bytes, 113504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdf34bf7e

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root: 464.82 GiB, 499076038656 bytes, 974757888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop8: 61.75 MiB, 64729088 bytes, 126424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 61.74 MiB, 64720896 bytes, 126408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 76.73 MiB, 80437248 bytes, 157104 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 77.16 MiB, 80904192 bytes, 158016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 131.3 MiB, 137392128 bytes, 268344 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 132.74 MiB, 139173888 bytes, 271824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop14: 268.76 MiB, 281792512 bytes, 550376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop15: 276.67 MiB, 290095104 bytes, 566592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop16: 140.67 MiB, 147488768 bytes, 288064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop17: 161.42 MiB, 169254912 bytes, 330576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop18: 140.68 MiB, 147492864 bytes, 288072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop19: 162.89 MiB, 170778624 bytes, 333552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop20: 243.94 MiB, 255762432 bytes, 499536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop21: 140 KiB, 143360 bytes, 280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop22: 132 KiB, 135168 bytes, 264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop23: 64.79 MiB, 67915776 bytes, 132648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop24: 65.1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop25: 112.54 MiB, 117989376 bytes, 230448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop26: 712.56 MiB, 747163648 bytes, 1459304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop27: 235.98 MiB, 247422976 bytes, 483248 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop28: 255.6 MiB, 267997184 bytes, 523432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop29: 260.73 MiB, 273375232 bytes, 533936 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop30: 289.8 MiB, 303853568 bytes, 593464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop31: 290.59 MiB, 304689152 bytes, 595096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop32: 323.52 MiB, 339222528 bytes, 662544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop33: 87.82 MiB, 92065792 bytes, 179816 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop34: 170.10 MiB, 179286016 bytes, 350168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop35: 2.34 MiB, 2445312 bytes, 4776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop36: 2.64 MiB, 2756608 bytes, 5384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop37: 92.86 MiB, 97353728 bytes, 190144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop38: 81.38 MiB, 85323776 bytes, 166648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop39: 191.84 MiB, 201134080 bytes, 392840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop40: 191.64 MiB, 200929280 bytes, 392440 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop41: 111.58 MiB, 116989952 bytes, 228496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop42: 111.58 MiB, 116981760 bytes, 228480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop43: 5.51 MiB, 5767168 bytes, 11264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop44: 5.54 MiB, 5799936 bytes, 11328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop45: 230.63 MiB, 241819648 bytes, 472304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop46: 295.67 MiB, 310018048 bytes, 605504 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop47: 354.25 MiB, 371453952 bytes, 725496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop48: 354.25 MiB, 371453952 bytes, 725496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop49: 27.33 MiB, 28651520 bytes, 55960 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop50: 38.9 MiB, 40771584 bytes, 79632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop51: 525.3 MiB, 550535168 bytes, 1075264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop52: 50.74 MiB, 53182464 bytes, 103872 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop53: 525.3 MiB, 550535168 bytes, 1075264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop54: 101.48 MiB, 106397696 bytes, 207808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop55: 124.32 MiB, 130347008 bytes, 254584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop56: 124.32 MiB, 130347008 bytes, 254584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop57: 65.32 MiB, 68489216 bytes, 133768 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop58: 65.31 MiB, 68476928 bytes, 133744 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop59: 134.6 MiB, 141119488 bytes, 275624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop60: 134.6 MiB, 141119488 bytes, 275624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop61: 59.2 MiB, 62070784 bytes, 121232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop62: 59.2 MiB, 62070784 bytes, 121232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop63: 57.2 MiB, 59969536 bytes, 117128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop64: 67.58 MiB, 70844416 bytes, 138368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop65: 301.12 MiB, 315748352 bytes, 616696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop66: 5.8 MiB, 6066176 bytes, 11848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop67: 301.13 MiB, 315756544 bytes, 616712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop68: 2.18 MiB, 2281472 bytes, 4456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop69: 4.25 MiB, 4448256 bytes, 8688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop70: 456.37 MiB, 478527488 bytes, 934624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop71: 2.7 MiB, 2166784 bytes, 4232 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop72: 456.41 MiB, 478568448 bytes, 934704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop73: 73.10 MiB, 77565952 bytes, 151496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop74: 337.72 MiB, 354107392 bytes, 691616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop75: 99.48 MiB, 104304640 bytes, 203720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop76: 40 KiB, 40960 bytes, 80 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop77: 303.8 MiB, 317796352 bytes, 620696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop78: 215.47 MiB, 225923072 bytes, 441256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop79: 337.72 MiB, 354111488 bytes, 691624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop80: 456.4 MiB, 478564352 bytes, 934696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Как разбили так и есть. А в чём тут собственно проблема? Я бы понял проблема - это когда нет свободного места и не понятно куда оно делось. Или если диск 1ГБ а сумарно вышло 0,5, а ещё 0,5 исщезло.

Comment: @nick_n_a Так дело в том, что я так не разбивал диск. И при просмотре туторов или чтении статей с решением какой-либо проблемы ни у кого не видел такого количества "лупов". Откуда они взялись? Да и названии сродни "цикла" меня немного настораживает. Может это для операционки? Или для каких нибудь серверных приложений нужно. Я бы их как нибудь убрал, но стремаюсь последствий.

Comment: @nick_n_a для меня это не проблема, а такой, сродни философскому, вопрос: для чего так много разделов с именем "loop" + n? Откуда они взялись? Может ли полететь система или что либо ещё, если их снести?

Comment: @nick_n_a жёсткий диск указан там же в выводе fdisk - после 7ого loop-а
Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0

Comment: Я понял, ниже разделы. Два, один основной, второй подкачки (swap). А вопрос тогда что такое собственно loop.

Comment: Вообще раздел у вас на жестком диске всего один. `/dev/sda1  *     2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G 8e Linux LVM` Который собственно отдан LVM который на нем уже сделал несколько своих логических. По поводу loop они используются когда вам надо смонтировать содержимое файла как файловую систему. `losetup -a` скажет вам что за файлы реально представлены этими loop, возможно это что то подскажет. Может у вас используются например виртуалки ?

Comment: @nick_n_a в том то и вопрос

Comment: @Mike Была виртуальная машина с 3-мя ОСями. Одна - Windows 7 для запуска Photoshop и Visual Studio (второе по учёбе), а так же Windows Server 2003 и Windows XP (для учёбы по сетям).

Comment: ну это тут точно не причем. что losetup То говорит ?

Comment: @Mike Так блэт, шо то я не понял, это типа snap так забирает пространство?

```➜  ~ losetup -a        
/dev/loop1: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/boa_215.snap)
/dev/loop29: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-core18_32.snap)
/dev/loop57: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/powershell_158.snap)
/dev/loop19: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_145.snap)
/dev/loop47: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/onlyoffice-desktopeditors_67.snap)
/dev/loop75: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/wine-platform-3-stable_11.snap)
/dev/loop37: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ktouch_73.snap)

```

И так ещё овердохрена строчек

Comment: Ну вот это все объясняет. первый раз слышу про snapd, но собственно гугл сразу ответил на вопрос что это https://www.xelent.ru/blog/snapy-v-ubuntu-chto-eto-takoe-i-s-chem-ego-edyat/  Это ваш дистрибутив часть пакетов устанавливает для совместимости в виде образов

Comment: @Mike а это считается нормальным?)

Comment: да, без этого современные системы не работают. ну или работают, но обновить их проблематично. собственно как на старых дистрибутивах всегда было

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device

Comment: @Mike - "без этого современные системы не работают." На самом деле, в **современных** дистрибутивах отказываются от использования snap. Просто потому, что идея совершенно идиотская - для каждого пакета тащить **все** зависимости. - "или работают, но обновить их проблематично." - В самом деле ? :-) 20 лет на люнихе работаю - никаких проблем с обновлением не было. А вот появился snap - такой гемморой начался, что мама не горюй!

Comment: "Снап можно считать таким пакетом, в котором содержится не только программа, но и **все необходимые для ее работы библиотеки**." - т.е. если я установил два снап-пакета, использующих Qt, то у меня на диски запишется два образа библиотеки Qt. Библиотека сама по себе - огромная. Плюс тащит за собой множество зависимостей, которые тоже нужно упаковать в снап... Можно ли придумать что-то более несуразное?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/dev/loop это виртуальные устройства.

Судя по их количеству у вас что-то запущенно в Docker.

Докер использует несколькообразов жесткого диска накладывая их друг на друга слоями. На одну гостевую систему полочается 4-8 слоев.

О, в комментах увидел snap - эта штука создает такие же слои для каждого приложения.